# rails + escape_javascript + locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the below jquery script and I can't pass i value into locales=> :val

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var i = 1

  function more(){

     var information= $("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'info', :locals => { :val => i }) %>");

     i = i+1;
  }

});
```

Please guide me how to pass javascript variable to rails.

Thanks

Comment: Wait, wait, wait... Rails code is interpreted in the server, and javascript in the client browser. You cannot pass a javascript variable to a rails partial tag.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe I can provide a solution if I know more details.

Comment: each time when i call the function more, form should render partial and pass i value to the partial

Answer (score 0):

If possible values of the variable i are limited, you could generate javascript for every possible value of i. e.g.: (i is in range 1..10)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 1
  var informationArray = new Array();
  <% (1..10).each do |num| %>
    informationArray[<%= num %>] = $("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'info', :locals => { :val => num }) %>");
  <% end %>

  function more(){
    var information = informationArray[i];
    i = i+1; 
  }

});
```

Otherwise, if variable i is not limited in a specific small range, you should use AJAX to send the parameter to the server and retrieve the information for that value.